# How to call multiple buttons to do the same function in tweenmax?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, gsap

I am currently using tweenMax to do a website and I would like to ask if there is anyone know tweenmax are alble to do something like array which means with 1 simple line of code to call a few buttons to do a same function. Below are my current code which I need to copy and paste if new button added.

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    TweenMax.staggerTo([box4, box3, box2, box, box8, box7, box6, box5, box9, ], 1,  {right:"-25000", ease:Quad.easeIn}, 0.05);
};

btn2.onclick = function() {
    TweenMax.staggerTo([box4, box3, box2, box, box8, box7, box6, box5, box9, ], 1,  {right:"-25000", ease:Quad.easeIn}, 0.05);
};

btn3.onclick = function() {
    TweenMax.staggerTo([box4, box3, box2, box, box8, box7, box6, box5, box9, ], 1,  {right:"-25000", ease:Quad.easeIn}, 0.05);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fusion's answer is correct and useful if you are using jQuery. If you'd like to avoid dependency on jQuery, then assume you have an array of buttons such as `var buttons = [btn, btn2, btn3]` and a function:

```
function tweenClickHandler() {
  TweenMax.staggerTo([box4, box3, box2, box, box8, box7, box6, box5, box9, ], 1,  {right:"-25000", ease:Quad.easeIn}, 0.05);
};
```

you could attach tweenClickHandler to each element in `buttons` with:

```
buttons.forEach(function(button) {button.onclick = tweenClickHandler;});
```

Note that forEach won't work on IE < 9 natively, but can be added using the polyfill provided by the Mozilla Developers Network documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is okay for you, just use jQuery selector:

```
    $(btn,btn2,btn3).click(function() {
        TweenMax.staggerTo([box4, box3, box2, box, box8, box7, box6, box5, box9, ], 1,  {right:"-25000", ease:Quad.easeIn}, 0.05);
    });
```

jQuery selector Hint:

```
$("#firstbutton , #secondbutton , #thirdbutton") // Select buttons directly by ID

$(".buttons") // Select buttons by class.
```